# How to Log Third-Party Import Module Errors in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a raspberry pi code and I am going to deploy it to many devices. I have prepared logging method to log different types of information to a file. However, I am not able to log error of ImportModule error as import statements happen at the tip of the file. It would be very convenient for me as I am deploying the app to many devices, so capturing even log module error would be helpful to ease diagnosis

In order to solve this. I have included the import inside the main function inside try-catch block.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:        
        import serial
        import requests
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Exception occurred', exc_info=True)
        logging.getLogger().handlers[0].flush()
```

Is that a good practice or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You may catch `ImportError` instead of `Exception` since you already know that you may end up with import error while importing the packages.